# Generating RSS Feed Quote Marks Issue

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm pulling data from a table to generate an itunes feed.

The format for the category tag is :

```
<itunes:category text="Games &amp; Hobbies">
</itunes:category>
```

I'm fetching this value i.e. the category, from a field in a table.

This :

```
<itunes:category text=".$data['category']."</itunes:category>
```

Outputs :

```
<itunes:category text=Games &amp; Hobbies</itunes:category>
</itunes:category>
```

Instead of :

```
<itunes:category text="Games &amp; Hobbies">
</itunes:category>
```

It's missing the speech marks around the category. I've tried all sorts of combinations of brackets but keep getting syntax errors.

Full script below :

```
<?php
  include("authenticate.php");
  $user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
  $initialdata = $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccregisterfeed WHERE username = '$user'");
  $initdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($initialdata);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ccshowcontent JOIN ccaudio ON ccshowcontent.id = ccaudio.id WHERE ccshowcontent.username = '$user' ORDER BY ccshowcontent.id DESC")
or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $items[] = $row;
}

function createXML($items,$data){

    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/DTDs/Podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>".$data['feedtitle']."</title>
<link>".$data['websitelink']."</link>
<language>en-GB</language>
<copyright>".$data['copyright']."</copyright>
<itunes:subtitle>".$data['subtitle']."</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:author>".$data['author']."</itunes:author>
<description>".$data['feeddescription']."</description>
<itunes:image href=".$data['imagelink']."/>
<itunes:category text=".$data['category']."</itunes:category>
<title>".$data['feedtitle']."</title>
<link>".$data['websitelink']."</link>
<category text=>".$data['category']."</category>
<pubDate>".date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($data['pubdate']))."</pubDate>
<language>en-us</language>
<image>
<title>".$data['feedtitle']."</title>
<link>".$data['websitelink']."</link>
<url>".$data['imagelink']."</url>
<description>".$data['imagetitle']."</description>
</image>";

$audiodir = "http://thetradingcardgenerator.com/MP3/";
foreach($items as $key => $item){
    $path = $audiodir.$item['path'];
    $pdate = strtotime($item['pubdate']);
    $date = date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", $pdate);
    $xml .="
<item>
<title>".$item['title']."</title>
<description>".$item['description']."></description>
<guid>".$path."</guid>
<pubDate>".$date."</pubDate>
<itunes:duration>".$data['imagelink']."</itunes:duration>
</item>";

}

$xml .="
</channel>
</rss>";

return $xml;
}

$rss = createXML($items,$initdata);
//echo "feed updated!";
$filename = "itunes" . strtolower(str_ireplace(" ", "", $initdata['feedtitle']) . ".xml");
file_put_contents($filename,$rss);
header("Location: ccupload.php?message=".urlencode("Content Added <br/> Feed Updated"));
// var_dump ($filename);
?>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes, escaping and closing >. I suggest using an XML library to generate the XML or a least be careful and use htmlspecialchars().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing some quotes and a closing angle bracket:

```
"...<itunes:category text=\"".$data['category']."\"></itunes:category>..."
                          ^^                     ^^^
```

If you're still getting syntax errors after you fix that, update your question with the exact error message.

Comment: But the "other" tag values are XML node values (values between an opening and closing tag), not *attribute* values (properties on a node itself). `text` here is an *attribute* value, and those need to be quoted.